# jQuery requests undefined url (used with phpdevshell)

Tags: jquery

I'm creating an app using phpdevshell (which uses latest jQuery).

Now without any reason visible to me, jQuery started requesting an url ending with "undefined" which doesn't exist and causes 404.

It looks for this url: http://localhost/mysite/undefined

I've located the part of jQuery that does this (starting at line 7866):

```
// Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Please add context: the code (and surroundings) from where the request is created.

Comment: Which version of jQuery ? Are you completely sure you're not calling this url using some jQuery-ajax-related method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're building an url with a variable that returns undefined. Ie: var url = " http://localhost/mysite/" + variable; where variable is undefined.

Comment: Thanks and +1 to everyone, all your answers joint helped me figure this. I use an upload plugin, but was initiating it from every page, instead just from one where it's relevant. So I had 404 on all pages except that one. All good now:)

Answer (score 1):

Try puting `return false` at the end of your function. May be it is propagating for another event.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... try updating jquery in folder /themes/cloud/js/combined-min-305.js it might just be an annoying Jquery 3.0.5 bug.