# "undefined" randomly appended in 1% of requested urls on my website since 12 june 2012

Tags: javascript, browser

Since 12 june 2012 11:20 TU, I see very weirds errors in my varnish/apache logs.

Sometimes, when a user has requested one page, several seconds later I see a similar request but the all string after the last / in the url has been replaced by "undefined".

Example:
**http://example.com/foo/bar** triggers a **http://example.com/foo/undefined** request.

Of course theses "undefined" pages does not exist and my 404 page is returned instead (which is a custom page with a standard layout, not a classic apache 404)

- This happens with any pages (from the homepage to the deepest)
- with various browsers, (mostly Chrome 19, but also firefox 3.5 to 12, IE 8/9...) but only 1% of the trafic.
- The headers sent by these request are classic headers (and there is no ajax headers).
- For a given ip, this seems occur randomly: sometimes at the first page visited, sometimes on a random page during the visit, sometimes several pages during the visit...

Of course it looks like a javascript problem (I'm using jquery 1.7.2 hosted by google), but **I've absolutely nothing changed in the js/html or the server configuration** since several days and I never saw this kind of error before. And of course, there is no such links in the html.

I also noticed some interesting facts:

- the undefined requests are never found as referer of another pages, but instead the "real" pages were used as referer for the following request of the same IP (the user has the ability to use the classic menu on the 404 page)
- I did not see any trace of these pages in Google Analytics, so I assume no javascript has been executed (tracker exists on all pages including 404)
- nobody has contacted us about this, even when I invoked the problem in the social networks of the website
- most of the users continue the visit after that

All theses facts make me think the problem occurs silently in the browers, probably triggered by a buggy add-on, antivirus, a browser bar or a crappy manufacturer soft integrated in browsers updated yesterday (but I didn't find any add-on released yesterday for chrome, firefox and IE).

Is anyone here has noticed the same issue, or have a more complete explanation?

Comment: Some JavaScript code on your pages is constructing URLs, and it's got one or more bugs. Software, without being changed itself, can change behavior due to browser updates, sensitivity to date/time, 3rd part script changes, etc. Without seeing the code, it's going to be impossible to tell exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @colinux What server side language do you use?

Comment: Got the exact same problem - Furthermore I also get a lot of URL/cache/RANDOM. Something like: http://www.mysite.com/somePage.aspx/cache/d4a8bc7342d - Seems the random part is hex numbers. It could be a subset of a GUID.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, for some reason recently got more of those requests. @Steffen the /cache/xxxx requests may be to some kind of a bot searching for vulnerabilities, the site I'm working on receives tons of requests like "/admin/file_manager.php/login.php"

Comment: @Dmitry I don't think it's a bot, since my log includes session information. These requests come from logged in users, and not just a few either - they seem to come from a lot of different users, so I'm thinking it might be some prefetch engine of sorts screwing up. I've only observed the /cache/xxxx requests from Chrome v. 19, which further strengthens my belief in an error in the browser.

Comment: You're right, and I'm also receiving requests to "/cache/7a226e8aa3a4380444a329a7b0dd0f40". Either browser or some kind of a popular add-on

Comment: Just a tip/idea for debugging:
 - Place a clear message on your 404 page stating in fairly big letters "If you see this, could you please contact x@y.z describing how you got here" (possibly only shown if `location.href.search("undefined")` is true).
 - If no emails and you use jquery ajax everywhere, wrap the jquery ajax call in a custom function which first checks whether the returned data is a JSON and whether data.undefinedError exists and if it exists log it somewhere (+create a check in your 404 which returns `{undefinedError:true}` if there is `undefined` in the url).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228250/jquery-requests-undefined-url-used-with-phpdevshell ?

Comment: The previous comment was of course assuming it's not a browser or extension issue if it's caused by different browsers. (although anti virus issue could still theoretically be applicable). Lastly it might be useful to check all external resources (e.g. jquery) and set them to an older version.

Comment: I am experiencing this too and neither think it is a bot.
Both the /cache/xxxx and the /undefined However it is not only Chrome 19, but also IE 8 and 9.

Comment: I also had the /cache/<md5sum> issue for a while, but only with Chrome so I guessed a buggy extension caused this. The thing here it affects several browsers on several websites, but not all websites. I continue to investigate, but I think jquery is the common denominator. And I'm pretty sure this is transparent to users because noone had reported this issue (I usually have feedbacks when a problem occurs). So it's maybe an antivirus, or a virus on their computers?

Comment: If you post a sample URL we would be able to debug your issue.

Comment: Example: www.composite.net I'm not using jQuery, nearly the only external js library used is Google Analytics

Comment: So if jQuery is not the common denominator, this renforces the theory of a browser/software issue only. Example for me: statistiks.com . I'm using jquery + pjax (but not enabled for IE) and some other libraries but once again, I don't changed anything at the moment when the problem started.

Comment: could it be google analytic's script itself?

Comment: Third party scripts (analytics, social bookmarking, javascript powered toolbars etc) might be the culprit.

Comment: Funnily last night I got a debug email from one of my websites with a 'undefined' on the page. I think it's a similar issue. there are no broken links on the page. I can only assume it's some kind of scraper or something, as the page it happened on is not one that would get visited very often, or at the time is was visited. The IP address seems to be UK, and the agent is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5` as reported to me by asp.net

Comment: This is a thought, browsers like chrome can have a "sneek Peak" option turned on this means that the browser is both connecting and running but if they user hits return after they finished the url in there address bar the page is reloaded though cache if a anti-cache method is not implemented it might be that the error is from that but then that would not explain about IE as some one has comented

Comment: do you have addons|advertise|publicity in your page?

Comment: I've been also experiencing {domain}/undefined errors since 12 June. I tried to remove ALL javascript from my site (google analytics, adsense, etc), but errors still appear. Every day the number of them is increasing.
Almost all errors are generated by users who use Chrome of different versions.
I suspect that it is some extensions or add-in, but can't reproduce on my own pc.
I also mentioned that request containing /undefined is always followed after the correct page request with the all subrequest (images, css, etc)

Comment: Another report, also that it began on June 12: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/G1snYHaHSOc

Comment: I'm seeing this kind of requests on my website, mostly from Chrome, IE 8, couple from IE9 and I got one from FF15.

I don't have my javascript code on the affected pages, but I do have a lot of third party scripts (Analytics, AdSense, Twitter, Google+, Facebook and AddThis buttons). If someone can just narrow it down by saying which of this scripts you use on your websites.

Comment: I am also seeing a lot of these requests (both /cache/xxxx and /undefined) and been unable to reproduce. I think the conclusion from the chromium thread about the /cache/xxx requests looks right (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059). That is that the requests are caused by a browser extension (probably Browser Companion Helper). Strange thing is this extension must then be available on all browsers because I see these requests coming from all browser types.

Comment: [@epommate on Google Groups](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/G1snYHaHSOc/p8RLCohxz2kJ) tracked it down to a plugin. @Thomas further down claims `The plugin checks the name, class and id of an input field - I tested them individually. If anyone of these contain the word "search", it will trigger the undefined-error`. No better solution yet...

Comment: The issue for /cache/xx is explained there : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059#c47

Comment: I get these a lot.  Here's a curious example:

    Referrer: http://www.nestseekers.com/ForSale/beach_front_property/bronx/
    Requested URL: /ForSale/beach_front_property/bronx/undefined/
    User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
    IP address: 66.249.73.174

Now how could the google bot experience the error ? I guess if its running the javascript. but it probably rules out it being caused by a plugin.

Answer (score 22):

There is no simple straight answer.

You are going to have to debug this and it is probably JavaScript due to the 'undefined' word in the URL. However it doesn't have to be AJAX, it could be JavaScript creating any URL that is automatically resolved by the browser (e.g. JavaScript that sets the src attribute on an image tag, setting a css-image attribute, etc). I use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) with [Firebug](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) installed most of the time, so my directions will be with that in mind.

**Firebug Initial Setup**

*Skip this if you already know how to use Firebug.*

After the installs and restarting Firefox for Firebug, you are going to have to enable most of Firebug's 'panels'. To open Firebug there will be a little fire bug/insect looking thing in the top right corner of your browser or you can press F12. Click through the Firebug tabs 'Console', 'Script', 'Net' and enable them by opening them up and reading the panel's information. You might have to refresh the page to get them working properly.

**Debugging User Interaction**

Navigate to one of the pages that has the issue with Firebug open and the Net panel active. In the Net panel there will be a few options: 'Clear', 'Persist', 'All', 'Html', etc. Make sure ALL is selected. Don't do anything on the page and try not to mouse over anything on it. Look through the requests. The request for the invalid URL will be red and probably have a status of 404 Not Found (or similar).

See it on load? Skip to the next part.

Don't see it on initial load? Start using your page and continue here.

Start clicking on every feature, mouse over everything, etc. Keep your eyes on the Net panel and watch for a requests that fail. You might have to be creative, but continue using your application till you see your browser make an invalid request. If the page makes many requests, feel free to hit the 'Clear' button on the top left of the Net panel to clear it up a bit.

If you submit the page and see a failed request go out really quick but then lose it because the next page loads, enable persistence by clicking 'Persist' in the top left of the Net panel.

Once it does, and it should, consider what you did to make that happen. See if you can make it happen again. After you figure out what user interaction is making it happen, dive into that code and start looking for things that are making invalid requests.

You can use the Script tab to setup breakpoints in your JavaScript and step through them. Investigate event handlers done via $(elemment).bind/click/focus/etc or from old school event attributes like onclick=""/onfocus="" etc.

**If the request is happening as soon as the page loads**

This is going to be a little harder to peg down. You will need to go to the Script tab and start adding break points to every script that runs on load. You do this by clicking on the left side of the line of JavaScript.

Reload your page and your break points should stop the browser from loading the page. Press the 'Continue' button on the script panel. Go to your net panel and see if your request was made, continue till it is found. You can use this to narrow down where the request is being made from by slowly adding more and more break points and then stepping into and out of functions.

**What you are looking for in your code**

Something that is similar to the following:

```
var url = workingUrl + someObject['someProperty'];

var url = workingUrl + someObject.someProperty;
```

Keep in mind that someObject might be an object `{}`, an array `[]`, or any of the internal browser types. The point is that a property will be accessed that doesn't exist.

**I don't see any 404/red requests**

Then whatever is causing it isn't being triggered by your tests. Try using more things. The point is you should be able to make the request happen somehow. You just don't know yet. It has to show up in the Net panel. The only time it won't is when you aren't doing whatever triggers it.

**Conclusion**

There is no super easy way to peg down what exactly is going on. However using the methods I outlined you should be at least  be able to get close. It is probably something you aren't even considering.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already have tried to inspect this with firebug and by watching my varnish/apache logs on my ip, without success. Theses "undefined" requests represent less than 1% of all html requests, and all types of pages are concerned, so it's really hard to trigger them. But next week I'll try again, with different browsers and I'll investigate more deeply the event handlers like you said. Thanks!

Comment: I'm betting that it's more likely that it's just something like `var url = omeObject['usuallyAURL'];`, and that's getting set as the src or href of some requested asset, and is thus treated as a relative path request. ie, `<img src="undefined" />`

Answer (score 17):

Based on this [post](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/G1snYHaHSOc/p8RLCohxz2kJ), I reverse-engineered the "Complitly" Chrome Plugin/malware, and found that this extension is injecting an "improved autocomplete" feature that was throwing "undefined" requests at every site that has a input text field with NAME or ID of "search", "q" and many others.

I found also that the enable.js file (one of complitly files) were checking a global variable called "suggestmeyes_loaded" to see if it's already loaded (like a Singleton). So, setting this variable to false disables the plugin.

To disable the malware and stop "undefined" requests, apply this to every page with a search field on your site:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.suggestmeyes_loaded = true;
</script>
```

This malware also redirects your users to a "searchcompletion.com" site, sometimes showing competitors ADS. So, it should be taken seriously.

Comment: I am seeing this in my logs too, with pages where it can't possibly be JS; I believe you are 100% correct.  Though I wonder how long it will be before the malware changes the name of this variable.

Comment: sounds quite plausible in my case.  

one exception: 

Requested URL: /ForSale/beach_front_property/bronx/undefined/

User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

not sure why the googlebot would find and follow that. unless they detected the URL somewhere and went to go have a look see.  but the bot states a correct referrer url

Comment: another exception: User agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16

Complitly is not available for Opera

also I see a lot of Linux, Android, and NT

Comment: @felix One place Googlebot learns about URLs is from Chrome users when the browser "phones home"

Answer (score 8):

You have correctly established that the `undefined` relates to a JavaScript problem and if your site users haven't complained about seeing error pages, you could check the following.

> If JavaScript is used to set or change image locations, it sometimes happens that an `undefined` makes its way into the URI.

When that happens, the browser will happily try to load the image (no AJAX headers), but it will leave hints: it sets a particular `Accept:` header; instead of `text/html, text/xml, ...` it will use `image/jpeg, image/png, ...`.

Once such a header is confirmed, you have narrowed down the problem to images only. Finding the root cause will possibly take some time though :)

**Update**

To help debugging you could override `$.fn.attr()` and invoke the debugger when something is being assigned to undefined. Something like this:

```
​(function($, undefined) {
    var $attr = $.fn.attr;

    $.fn.attr = function(attributeName, value) {
        var v = attributeName === 'src' ? value : attributeName.src;

        if (v === 'undefined') {
            alert("Setting src to undefined");
        }

        return $attr(attributeName, value);
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: You're right, I could have a lead thanks to headers. When it's a Chrome request, the headers are (sorry for the bad formatting in comments)
`Host: statistiks.fr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
Accept: */*
Referer: http://statistiks.fr/basket-ball/[..]
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
[...]`

But with IE9, the Accept header referers to an image:
`Accept: image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5`

Next week I will take time to investigate on the images side. Thanks!

Comment: @colinux I've updated my answer to help you find the problem easier. Let me know if you'd have any problems applying that.

Answer (score 3):

Some facts that have been established, especially in this thread: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/G1snYHaHSOc/p8RLCohxz2kJ

it happens on pages that have no javascript at all.
this proves that it is not an on-page programming error

the user is unaware of the issue and continues to browse quite happily.

it happens a few seconds after the person visits the page.

it doesn't happen to everybody.

happens on multiple browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox, Mobile Safari, Opera)

happens on multiple operating systems (Linux, Android, NT)

happens on multiple web servers (IIS, Nginx, Apache)

I have one case of googlebot following the link and claiming the same referrer. They may just be trying to be clever and the browser communicated it to the mothership who then set out a bot to investigate.

I am fairly convinced by the proposal that it is caused by plugins.  Complitly is one, but that doesn't support Opera. There many be others.

Though the mobile browsers weigh against the plugin theory.

Sysadmins have reported a major drop off by adding some javascript on the page to trick Complitly into thinking it is already initialized.

Here's my solution for nginx:

```
location ~ undefined/?$  {
  return 204;
}
```

This returns "yeah okay, but no content for you".

If you are on website.com/some/page and you (somehow) navigate to website.com/some/page/undefined the browser will show the URL as changed but will not even do a page reload. The previous page will stay as it was in the window.

If for some reason this is something experienced by users then they will have a clean noop experience and it will not disturb whatever they were doing.

Comment: Your solution definitely saved me from the fallout of this.  The browser was complaining about mixed content (ssl and plain), now this is solved, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a race condition where a variable is not getting properly initialized before getting used. Considering this is not an AJAX issue according to your comments, there will be a couple of ways of figuring this out, listed below.

**Hookup a Javascript exception Logger**: this will help you catch just about all random javascript exceptions in your log. Most of the time programmatic errors will bubble up here. Put it before any scripts. You will need to catch these on the server and print them to your logs for analysis later. This is your first line of defense. Here is an example:

```
window.onerror = function(m,f,l) {
    var e = window.encodeURIComponent;
    new Image().src = "/jslog?msg=" + e(m) + "&filename=" + e(f) + "&line=" + e(l) + "&url=" + e(window.location.href);
};
```

**Search for window.location**: for each of these instances you should add logging or check for undefined concats/appenders to your window.location. For example:

```
function myCode(loc) {
    // window.location.href = loc; // old 
    typeof loc === 'undefined' && window.onerror(...); //new
    window.location.href = loc; //new
}
```

or the slightly cleaner:

```
window.setLocation = function(url) { 
   /undefined/.test(url) ? 
         window.onerror(...) : window.location.href = url;       
}

function myCode(loc) {
    //window.location.href = loc; //old
    window.setLocation(loc); //new
}
```

If you are interested in getting stacktraces at this stage take a look at: https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace

**Grab all unhandled undefined links**: Besides window.location The only thing left are the DOM links themselves. The third step is to check all unhandeled DOM links for your invalid URL pattern (you can attach this right after jQuery finishes loading, earlier better):

```
$("body").on("click", "a[href$='undefined']", function() {
    window.onerror('Bad link: ' + $(this).html()); //alert home base
});
```

Hope this is helpful. Happy debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this might be an adblocker issue.  When I search through the logs by IP address it appears that every request by a particular user to /folder/page.html is followed by a request to /folder/undefined

Comment: I think this is related to software on the client too. Based on recent logs, this only happens for specific IP adresses and it seems to happen consistently for those as well. I see BTRS123368 and AskTbORJ/5.15.2.23037 in the user agent string, maybe it is related to one of those.

Comment: I got some more results: someone with FunWebProducts in the user agent is also requesting /undefined URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but my website is replacing one particular *.webp image file with undefined after it's loaded in multiple browsers. Is your site hosting webp images?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (but with `/null` 404 errors in the console) that @andrew-martinez's answer helped me to resolve.

Turns out that I was using `img` tags with an empty `src` field:

`<img src="" alt="My image" data-src="/images/my-image.jpg">`

My idea was to prevent browser from loading the image at page load to manually load later by setting the src attribute from the data-src attribute with javascript (lazy loading). But when combined with iDangerous Swiper, that method caused the error.