# "Undefined" appearing sometimes in the URL of my ASP.NET application (somehow google related?)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, undefined

Some users repeatedly run into a very mysterious problem when using my web application.

In the middle of using it, they'll click a button or link that takes them to another page, but there will be a "page not found" error, because the URL is something like:

http://www.correctwebsitename.com/**undefined**

I thought it might be a **javascript bug** in my app: a redirect done by choosing a page name (maybe with some parameters) where one of the values is bad, resulting in the page name = "undefined". But there is **no such code in my app** anywhere, and this **happens on many different pages, seemingly at random**.

The one thing that seems to make it happen more often is if the user logged in originally by **clicking a link in an email message in gmail**. But a user who cut and pasted the link URL into a browser window said it still happened. Googling around reveals some hints that **some kind of Google redirecting or caching is happening behind the scenes**.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I'm not getting responses from anyone familiar with how gmail links etc work, does anyone know what SO tags google experts "hang around in"?

**Edit 2:**
Awarding bounty to top answer for useful info and temporary workaround idea, but still interested in real solution to the problem, so not accepting workaround as solution.

Comment: @Trinh  As I said, there is no particular code that appears to be related to this issue. (I can't give you the entire source code to the application, I don't own it).

Comment: Well it's hard to tell you what happend, please try to scan all your code, find something like `window.location.href = somevariable` and make sure somevariable is not undefined....

Comment: Thanks @Trinh, but as I said, I already looked for those. There is nowhere in the code where a destination URL is created using javascript. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I was just wondering if there were some routing rule in the global.asax that could be causing it.

Comment: @IrishChieftain Yes, but only this: `routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");`

Comment: Have you done a solution-wide search for 'undefined'?

Comment: Is the site public? Can we **see** the problem?

Comment: Have you ever reproduced it yourself?  Sometimes a popular browser plugin can cause such unusual behavior ... AdBlock, I'm talking about you!

Comment: And, what Google code are you talking about? Do you have any particular Google code on your page?

Comment: @Adam Eberlin No, it's not a public site, it's only for paying users.

Comment: @Scott Rippey No google code in my web app, rather I suspect google does something sneakily behind the scenes when clicking on a link in gmail. Your status bar shows some long random google URL for a split second sometimes, like it's redirecting or something. Very strange.

Comment: @IrishChieftain yes, did a search for "undefined" in code already.

Comment: Do you see a request to an "undefined" URL in your IIS logs?

Comment: @Michael Liu I haven't checked, as I've seen it appear in the browser's address bar.

Comment: I'd check in the IIS logs just to be sure, and I'd also see what the referring URLs are.

Comment: As Scott said, sounds like something broken adware/anti-adware could do. Does the problem persist in different browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undefined" randomly appended in 1% of requested urls on my website since 12 june 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017609/undefined-randomly-appended-in-1-of-requested-urls-on-my-website-since-12-jun)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are right about gmail doing something with the links. See the gmail image below:

[image: gmail]

*Non-standard header fields are conventionally marked by prefixing the field name with X-*

Its probably behaving like... oh well, Google, and inspecting everything.

To stop google search from tracking my clicks i had to create a userscript to rewrite one of their functions:

```
rwt = function(){};
```

Maybe you can try something similar for gmail.

---

> *What is rwt?*

`rwt()` is a javascript function from google search that rewrites the links to track which site you have visited.

for example, searching for "greasemonkey" showed the mozilla addons page as the first result. clicking on it opened

`https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddons.mozilla.org%2Fpt-BR%2Ffirefox%2Faddon%2Fgreasemonkey%2F&ei=iWNtUIXjIoyQ8wTxv4DQAQ&usg=AFQjCNEO9EJcHp9rAmKyD_XZF2Bt6hs_YQ&sig2=P19xVUsD-Q1G_9AiUBP3PQ`

and then redirected to

`https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/`

The image above and the `rwt()` case is just to show you that there is a great chance that gmail is changing the links, so this could be related to your problem.

---

Since there is nothing you can do at gmail's side, maybe you could fix it on your server, by redirecting `http://www.correctwebsitename.com/undefined` to `http://www.correctwebsitename.com` or any other page that you'd like your users to see.

So, be it from gmail or any other referer, every time a client lands on `http://www.correctwebsitename.com/undefined` redirect him to another page.

---

> *so maybe I can figure out how to just send them back to the page they
>   came from*

**ASP**

```
if not request.UrlReferrer is nothing then
    response.redirect (request.UrlReferrer.tostring)
end if
```

**JS** (for this to work, you would have to actually create a page called `undefined`)

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('undefined') > -1) {
    // this works
    window.location.href = document.referrer;

    // this works too (uncomment to enable)
    // history.back();
}
```

*remember that if the user directly typed the url or used the link from favorites there wont be no referrer*

Comment: This sounds relevant, but I don't quite understand. Is gmail blocking your website due to XSS concerns? What is rwt? If your fix might be adapted to my situation, how would I do it? Userscripts work for your own browser, but how would I do something similar for my whole website?

Comment: Redirecting `http://www.correctwebsitename.com/undefined` somewhere sounds like a good temporary workaround (although it happens on all sorts of places - e.g.: step 2 of sign-up process, a report page, etc - so maybe I can figure out how to just send them back to the page they came from - then the user will just think the click didn't work instead of thinking it's an "error". Clicking again works fine, usually.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check the below things in your application.

**Is there any code in your application, apart from what you own ?**

there can be injected code by third party applications, like for ex "AddThis" adds an extra #parameter to your url sometimes, in your case its clear that a javascript is trying to playaround with the location.href as "undefined" is something which many js developers will come across.

by adding an # will help do cross site communication, some bug might also be causing an issue here.

**Do a complete search in your code for "location.href" and see if you have used it anywhere.**

**Sometimes third party addons on the browser too might cause this issue**

hope these would help you narrow down to your problem.

if you are not able to trace out the issue anywhere, i would suggest you to override 404 functionality on your webserver and implement the solution using Referrer.