# Jquery : noty confirmation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

I am using **JQuery noty plugin**. I need **Confirmation** message box, how ever the **Confirmation Message Box** comes fine along with **Buttons**, but the **Buttons Click Event** are not working. When i click any of the **Buttons**. It gives me 
**`HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.`
*`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`*** error. Below is my code.

```
 noty({
        text: 'Are you sure?',
        type: 'confirm',
        buttons: [
           {
               addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Ok', onClick: function ($noty) {
                   $noty.close();
                   noty({ text: 'You clicked "Ok" button', type: 'success' });
               }
           },
           {
               addClass: 'btn btn-danger', text: 'Cancel', onClick: function ($noty) {
                   $noty.close();
                   noty({ text: 'You clicked "Cancel" button', type: 'error' });
               }
           }
        ]
    })
```

whats wrong with this.

Comment: With using javascript confirm dialog box it appears on the screen and code execution is stopped at that point.
While using noty confirm box it only appears on the screen but code below is also executed. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the scripts are really loaded via firebug/devtools and if your paths are correct. Tested your code and it worked for me.

Comment: It changes the `URL` to `undefined`. what should be the mistake.?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the information you're giving. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017609/undefined-randomly-appended-in-1-of-requested-urls-on-my-website-since-12-jun